# Why am I getting this Error in Django notification?

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm using this one: https://github.com/pinax/django-notification/blob/master/docs/usage.txt

So, I followed all the steps.

```
from notification import models as notification

#first, create the notification type.
notification.create_notice_type("comment_received", ("Comment Received"), ("You have received a comment."))

#then, send the notification. 
notification.send(request.user, "comment_received", {})
```

Of course, in my template directory, I created "notification", just like the doc says.

Inside `/templates/notification/comment_received`, I have 4 files:

- full.txt, short.txt, notice.html, full.html

These files are blank right now. They just say a random sentence.

Why am I getting this error when I try to send the notification?

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'notification_notices' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you include the proper URL configurations? Looks like Django can't find notification_notices in any of your urlconfs...

https://github.com/pinax/django-notification/blob/master/notification/urls.py

You should reference these in your site's urls.py, e.g.:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^notification/', include(notification.urls)),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an entry in your `urls.py` file including the [django-nofication urls.py file](https://github.com/pinax/django-notification/blob/master/notification/urls.py):

```
(r'^notifications/', include('notification.urls')),
```

See the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) for more information on including other `urls.py` files.